# iOS update coreData when app updates

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm currently designing the architecture for an iOS app and have a question relating to the use of coreData to store values.

**The theory**
I'm looking to store values pertaining to specific items inside coreData along with specific user information that they set when using certain functionality.

**Updating**
When I release an update the app will update old values with new ones inside each entity. I'll use some version check before the code initialises to stop this happening on every load.

**Question**
When the app updates will it delete all values stored by the user or just the entities referenced in the update code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Core Data has version management. Just add new version:

[image]

Secondly, after version updated, Core Data will not delete stored values unless you deleted that attribute.

Comment: I can't see that picture, it's in  Edit--Add Model Version.

Comment: Thanks! The documentation was a little cryptic explaining how the new model worked against data.

Comment: Do we need to select the newly added version? Or the older version while uploading it to Appstore.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select xcdatamodeld first, then you can see "Add Model Version" in "Editor". then add "version name" -> finish. you can see new version added in folder. [image]